# Period between Heart lub-dup sound S1 and S2

Tags: cardiology, measurement, heartbeat, stethoscope

Just curious not asking a professional opinion, Does anyone know the average time difference between S1 and S2 sounds of the heart the so called lub-dup sound? 
I believe its around 150 milliseconds. 
What does it mean if that time difference (quadruples) goes well beyond 600 milliseconds?

Comment: While not specifically addressing the average time, depolarization starts in the SA node and travels through the heart causing contraction. If there is a delay in one spot, that *could* indicate damage as the electric signal reroutes. I don't remember my courses well enough to distinguish if this is in the correct spot for a bundle branch block.